# Global styles in ChakraUI for specific document

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I am working with ChakraUI and I want links that the user enters in the CMS in one big text block, to be underlined, but I don't want other links on my website to be underlined. I can change it in the global style, but that will change all of them on the website. What can I do to make this happen? Is there like a global style for a specific document only, or some way I can target all the `a` tags inside of a `p` tag?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `sx` props you will scope specifics styles :

```
<Box
  sx={{
    a: {
      textDecoration: "underline",
      color: "blue.500",
      _hover: {
        color: "blue.800"
      }
    }
  }}
>
  <p>Hello <Link href="#">Link</Link>.</p>
</Box>
```

Your targets can be more precise if you need :

```js
sx={{
  p: {
    a: { /* styles */ }
  }
}}
```

or :

```js
sx={{
  'p a': { /* styles */ }
}}
```

For more complete typographics styles for articles, you can also use the Prose package : https://chakra-ui.com/guides/recipes/prose